# Consider a finite probability space $\Omega$ with four elements

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is same as this one: [Consider a probability space $\Omega$ with four elements $a,b,c,d$. Define $\sigma$-algebra $F$ on $\Omega$-collection of subsets of $\Omega$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688619/consider-a-probability-space-omega-with-four-elements-a-b-c-d-define-sig).

However, my question $(a)$ is a little bit different from this link. Mine says to compute $\mathbb{E}(Y | X) (\omega)$ fr all $\omega \in \Omega$. You should check that the partial averaging property holds for all sets $A \in \sigma(X)$.

In this case I am little bit confused about the expression $\mathbb{E}(Y | X) (\omega)$ as based on my understanding, expectation is a function. How does it take another map? I have no idea what this question requires us to do.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $E(Y \mid X)$ is a function defined on $\Omega$, so for every $\omega \in \Omega$, $E(X \mid Y)(\omega)$ is a real number.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But I'm confused about this notation. What I learn previously about expectation would be like $E(X) = X \cdot P(X)$. But how does this notation derive?

Comment: Read page 205 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf $E(X \mid Y)$ is a conditional expectation, which is defined as the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the space of $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variables, that is, $E(X \mid Y)$ is the minimizer of $E((f(Y) - X)^2)$ over all measurable $f$. There are several rules for computing $E(X \mid Y)$ that resemble $\sum_{x} x p(x \mid y)$.